# Translate ffmpeg command to equivalent libav usage in C++?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, rtmp, ndi

How I can convert this ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -f libndi_newtek -i "COPPERYINPC (OBSNDI)"  -f flv "rtmp://192.168.31.166/live/stream
```

...to C++ API that can be complied in Ubuntu 18.04 with ffmpeg lib v3.4.12 and NDI lib v4.5.3?

Above , in fact, I want to push ndi to rtmp use C++ API ,not ffmpeg command.

compiled with gcc , running in Ubuntu 18.04 ,and I build in VS2019.